# Как удалять последнюю букву, и заново вставить

Tags: javascript

Есть слово (например: `Cheat`), нужно убрать `t` и потом снова поставить `t`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы определитесь, цифру вам надо убрать, или букву, или просто последнюю.

```js
let cheat = 'Cheat';
let chea = cheat.slice(0, -1);
let t = cheat.slice(-1);

console.log(chea, t, chea + t);
```

Comment: Извините) Не сообразил

Comment: И тут я не успел)))

Answer (score 2):

```js
let str = 'Cheat';

console.log('Начальная строка', str);

// Последний элемент строки
const last = str.length - 1;
// Сохраняем букву, для восстановления
const last_symbol = str[last];

str = str.slice(0, last);

console.log('Изменённая строка', str);

str = str + last_symbol;

console.log('Восстановленная строка', str);
```

> P.S. Элементарная задача, которую необходимо было решить самому.

Comment: я понимаю что это элементарная задача, увы, но я вообще ПО программист, нужно было кое-что сделать

Comment: @ПавелВороник желаю успехов. Вы могли бы лайкнуть мой ответ (если он вам понравился), но у вас мало репы.